# Install an earlier version of ethereum using apt-get on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ethereum, apt, go-ethereum, geth

How can we install an earlier version of the package `ethereum` when using Ubuntu 18.04?

The currently installed version is 1.8.12 and I will like 1.8.8.

```
# apt-cache policy ethereum
ethereum:
  Installed: 1.8.12+build14270+bionic
  Candidate: 1.8.12+build14270+bionic
  Version table:
     1.8.12+build14270+bionic 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

`geth` does not make the previous version available via the ppa. You will have to download them from https://geth.ethereum.org.